# using a sub-query to populate unpivot columns list

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery, unpivot

I currently do not have access to a server to test this out on, but how would I go about doing something like the following

```
UNPIVOT (X for XY IN (
SELECT column_name AS [XY]
    FROM Information_schema.Columns
    WHERE Table_name = XYZ AND column_name LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
)) AS unpivotedData
```

i.e. is it possible to dynamically populate a list of columns to unpivot rather than statically declare them

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use dynamic sql to do so. Refer to the following SO question:
[T-SQL Pivot? Possibility of creating table columns from row values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922797/t-sql-pivot-possibility-of-creating-table-columns-from-row-values)