# SQL Pivot Query with Dynamic Columns

Tags: sql, dynamic, pivot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [T-SQL Pivot? Possibility of creating table columns from row values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922797/t-sql-pivot-possibility-of-creating-table-columns-from-row-values)

I've been searching in vain for too long now and have to admit defeat and ask for help, I'm trying to modify a pivot query to produce a dynamic query of results from a table with data like this:

```
    UserId        PageViewed         DateTimeStamp
    1             Index.html         2011-12-01 13:55:01
    1             FAQ.html           2011-12-01 13:58:53
    1             ContactUs.html     2011-12-01 14:00:16
    2             Index.html         2011-12-01 15:55:01
    2             FAQ.html           2011-12-01 15:58:53
    2             ContactUs.html     2011-12-01 15:00:16
```

To show something like this, where the page number columns depend on the number of pages visited by a user:

```
    User        StartTime        Page1        Page2        Page3
    1           13:55:01         Index.hml    FAQ.html     ContactUs.html
    2           15:55:01         Index.hml    FAQ.html     ContactUs.html
```

I've managed it by hard coding the columns in, but obviously I don't want to keep changing the script to accomodate more and more pages.

So far I have something along the lines of:

```
    SELECT p.UserId, 
        CONVERT(TIME, MIN(p.DateTimeStamp), 7) StartTime,
        ISNULL(p.[1],'') Page1
        ISNULL(p.[1],'') Page2
        ISNULL(p.[1],'') Page3
    FROM
    (SELECT UserId
        ,DateTimeStamp
        ,PageViewed
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY DateTimeStamp) as pOrder
        FROM tbl) AS p
    PIVOT(MIN(PageViewed) FOR pOrder IN ([1],[2],[3]))
```

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The output here doesn't make sense to me. Can you provide a use case for this? Maybe there's a better way? I see top X pages being more appropriate for a pivot/report not every page as a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best example I've seen regarding dynamic pivoting is Itzik Ben-Gan's example. This related [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922797/t-sql-pivot-possibility-of-creating-table-columns-from-row-values) has a pretty good example of what you would need to do. Basically, you'll need to use some dynamic sql in order to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the response, although I'm unable to click through to the link you posted?

Comment: @SirBelmalot sorry about that. I updated the link.