# Convert multiple rows into one row with multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

I've a table containing information as follows:

```
idnumber     applic_id      cctype     ccnumber
---------  ------------    --------   ----------
    1           23            1         223445
    2           23            2         345567
```

I need a query that an make this:

```
idnumber     applic_id      cctype     ccnumber  idnumber     applic_id      cctype     ccnumber
---------  ------------    --------   ----------  ---------  ------------    --------   ----------
    1           23            1         223445       2           23            2         345567
```

Is anyone have a clue? I'm using PostgreSQL 8.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE` statements for simple queries.
Or use the `crosstab()` function of the [tablefunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html) module for more complex cases and better performance.

You can find examples for both cases under this related question:
[PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query)

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, but when I tried this crosstab function it gave me an error - "ERROR:  function crosstab(unknown) does not exist"

Comment: @dna: You need to install the additional module `tablefunc`. Follow my link and read my answer there.

Comment: I can't install anything because I'm not administrator on the server :) that is why I'll have to find another way to handle the problem :) thanks for the replay anyway :)

Comment: @dna I presented *two* alternatives. The linked question has answers for *both*.

Comment: Sorry but I'm new in this forum, and I can't find the answers in the link you presented, it just opens your profile.

Comment: @dna: That's my profile! :D The last line in my answer is a link! [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query)

Answer (score 0):

This is known as a PIVOT.

You can do it either with the PIVOT keyword which does not exist in PostgreSQL,  or using the poor-man's pivot like this:

**Poor Man's Pivot:**

- [Need to pivot or crosstab a table but not in the conventional way. please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750839/need-to-pivot-or-crosstab-a-table-but-not-in-the-conventional-way-please/8756894#8756894)
- [Poor Man's SQL Pivot. List Questions as Columns and Answers per User in one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924641/poor-mans-sql-pivot-list-questions-as-columns-and-answers-per-user-in-one-row)

Comment: This is tagged [PostgreSQL], there is no `PIVOT` keyword. You may be thinking of SQL Server.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, That is why the poor-man's pivot in the link.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, ok it was linked from the one I linked from!