# How to display selected results on one row instead of multiple rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I want to make my MS SQL 2008 select query display results in a very unique way that i hope somebody can help me accomplish.

Instead of having the results for 3 columns being displayed over 9 rows, i would like the data displayed in one row and have the 3 column names repeated 9 times.

I tried to Google this but i can't seem to find the right ideas anywhere.

Thanks a million to anyone that can help!

i wanted to post up pic's but i need rep points to do it which is so stupid! but any way i found a similar post that was answered for PostgreSQL 8.3. but i'm a total beginner so i don't understand how to translate is for MS SQL.

before:

```
col1 |  col2  |  col3   |
-----|--------|---------|
 a   |12/01/12| 13/01/12|
-----|--------|---------|
 b   |14/01/12| 14/01/12|
```

after:

```
col1 |  col2  |  col3   |col1 |  col2  |  col3   |
-----|--------|---------|-----|--------|---------|
 a   |12/01/12| 13/01/12| b   |14/01/12| 15/01/12|
-----|--------|---------|-----|--------|---------|
```

here's the link to give you a better idea of my situation 
[Convert multiple rows into one row with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744386/convert-multiple-rows-into-one-row-with-multiple-columns)

Comment: T-SQL does support PIVOT; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830960/how-to-pivot-table-with-t-sql - If thats not what your after it may help to provide a before & after example of your desired ouput

Comment: If you edit your post with your table structure, sample data and then the desired result, then I could alter my answer to be more specific to your needs.

Comment: @Lamak i can't post pic's because of my reputation points

Comment: @TravisStanley ok. I didn't ask you to post any pictures, though.

Comment: i meant to demonstrate what i wanted to know. i edited my post to illustrate my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005+ you can use the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to perform this. A *pivot* takes your values from rows and converts it into columns.

There are a few ways that you can pivot the data. If you know all of the values ahead of time, then you can hard-code you query.  Otherwise you could use dynamic SQL to generate the query at run-time.

A static version of a *pivot* would be similar to this:

```
select *
from
(
  select col1, col2
  from table1
) src
pivot
(
  max(col1)
  for col2 in (test, blah, value)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d93e/1).

If you have an unknown number of values, then you would generate dynamic SQL similar to this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(col2) 
                    from table1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select col1, col2
                from table1
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(col1)
                for col2 in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d93e/3)

These are taking the `col2` row values from your table and turning them into columns.  The result for both is the same:

```
| TEST | BLAH | VALUE |
-----------------------
|    1 |    2 |     3 |
```

Prior to SQL Server 2005 or in databases that do not have a *pivot* function, then you would use an aggregate function with a `case` expression to transform the data:

```
select 
  max(case when col2 = 'test' then col1 end) test,
  max(case when col2 = 'blah' then col1 end) blah,
  max(case when col2 = 'value' then col1 end) value
from table1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d93e/4)

One another way to do this if you want to repeat the columns, over and over again is to use the `UNPIVOT` and `PIVOT` function together to get the result.  If you have the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable
    ([id] int, [name] varchar(10), [type] varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO yourtable
    ([id], [name], [type])
VALUES
    (1, 'John', 'dog'),
    (2, 'Tim', 'bird'),
    (3, 'Betty', 'cat'),
    (4, 'Jim', 'rat')
;
```

And you want to repeat the `id`, `name` and `type` values in repeating columns, then you can use:

```
select *
from
(
  select 
    col +'_'+cast(rn as varchar(50)) col ,
    value
  from
  (
    select 
      cast(id as varchar(10)) id,
      name, 
      type,
      row_number() over(order by id) rn
    from yourtable
  ) src
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (id, name, type)
  ) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (id_1, name_1, type_1,
              id_2, name_2, type_2,
              id_3, name_3, type_3,
              id_4, name_4, type_4)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9df4/6).  The result of this will be:

```
| ID_1 | NAME_1 | TYPE_1 | ID_2 | NAME_2 | TYPE_2 | ID_3 | NAME_3 | TYPE_3 | ID_4 | NAME_4 | TYPE_4 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1 |   John |    dog |    2 |    Tim |   bird |    3 |  Betty |    cat |    4 |    Jim |    rat |
```

Edit #2, seeing your sample data you could use the following:

```
select *
from
(
  select 
    col +'_'+cast(rn as varchar(50)) col ,
    value
  from
  (
    select 
      col1,
      convert(varchar(10), col2, 120) col2, 
      convert(varchar(10), col3, 120) col3, 
      row_number() over(order by col1) rn
    from yourtable
  ) src
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (col1, col2, col3)
  ) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (col1_1, col2_1, col3_1,
              col1_2, col2_2, col3_2)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74e0a/7)

Gives the result:

```
| COL1_1 |     COL2_1 |     COL3_1 | COL1_2 |     COL2_2 |     COL3_2 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|      a | 2012-01-12 | 2012-01-13 |      b | 2012-01-14 | 2012-01-14 |
```

Comment: @TravisStanley I added a version more specific to your sample data.

Comment: @TravisStanley if you don't want to use `unpivot` and `pivot` you can use an `case` expression -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74e0a/11

Comment: +1. Sometimes I think that you deserve a medal. Well, badges are the closes thing on SO

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help i realy appreciate it, it's working :) made my weekend :)