# SQL Server : Querying Multiple Rows, Returning In One

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Problem**
We are currently working with some data which is stored as in the screenshot below. We are using this to display information in a C# application. The only way we can get the application to work as needed is to have the information in one single row.

We have tried some methods on [Display multiple rows and column values into a single row, multiple column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195709/display-multiple-rows-and-column-values-into-a-single-row-multiple-column-value) to no avail.

**Desired output**
We require each row with the same date and `vehicleID` to be on the same row to be output from our stored procedure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

[image: Current Dataset]

Comment: So if you "collapse" multiple rows into a single one - what should be used for the other columns (other than `vehicleID` and which date column exactly??)

Comment: Please normalize your data.

Comment: "The only way we can get the application to work as needed is to have the information in one single row." Can't the application be changed? Doing this in the database sounds like the wrong way to do it.

Comment: Hi @marc_s JobDate is the date we are looking at here cheers. I have also suggested the application be changed but I'm told this can't be done.

Comment: Are you asking about the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: @drigoangelo It's a little more complex than that.

Comment: Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understood correctly, you don't know how many unique date/vehicle_id combinations there are in the data.  hence you can't just do a pivot over a set list of values.

in this case, you would need to build up a list of the date/vehicle ids dynamically, and then pivot over that list.

please check out the following examples involving dynamic SQL and pivot tables:

[PIVOT in sql 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198716/pivot-in-sql-2005#199763)

[SQL Server : dynamic pivot over 5 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657214/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-over-5-columns)

[Pivot Dynamic Columns, no Aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985796/sql-server-pivot-dynamic-columns-no-aggregation)

https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2007/09/14/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005/

[SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

[Dynamic Pivot Columns in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797691/dynamic-pivot-columns-in-sql-server)

[SQL Pivot Query with Dynamic Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343417/sql-pivot-query-with-dynamic-columns)