# sql table pivot or transform

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have a table of data like the following

```
User Year  Points  Value
A    1997  1       10
A    1997  2       30
A    1997  3       40
A    1999  1       70
B    1993  1       7
B    1993  3       4
C    2001  1       10
.....
```

I want the table to be transformed as such:

```
User   Year  Points1  Points2  Points3 ....
A      1997  10       30       40
A      1999  70       null     null
B      1993  7        null     4
C      2001  10       null     null
......
```

The range of the Points is unknown at compile time, so it's not just from 1 to 3.
It almost like making the Points as the column header in the new table. I suppose SQL PIVOT is a good option, but I haven't got any luck playing with it. I'm using SQL 2008.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned `SQL PIVOT` I'm guessing  you're using SQL Server 2005 or later or Oracle 11g

**SQL 2005**

```
SELECT [user], year, [1] as Point1, [2] as Point2, [3] as Point3 
FROM
(

SELECT  [user], year , points, Value
    FROM table ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
SUM(Value)
FOR Points IN ([1], [2], [3])
) AS PivotTable
ORDER BY [user]
```

see working example at this [data.se query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60706/sample-for-9120559)

**Oracle 11g**

If you're using Oracle 11g it would be somthing like this (not sure about the field alias)

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
        SELECT  user, year , points, Value
        FROM table )
PIVOT  (SUM(Value) AS sum_value FOR (Points ) IN ('1' as Point1 , 
                                                  '2' as Point2, 
                                                 '3' as Point3))
Order by User;
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the range of the Points is unknown at compile time, so it's not just from 1 to 3

Comment: Well you'll need to do the above but with dynamic SQL see [T-SQL Pivot? Possibility of creating table columns from row values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2922815/119477)

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I tried your SQL, and get the User and Year columns right, but other columns show NULL.

Comment: It worked in the [data.se example](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60706/). You'd probably need to share your sql.

Comment: it seems to be the data that cause the problem, I used: ('J',1988, 1988, 10),
 ('W', 1989, 1989, 10),
 ('W', 1989, 1990, 20),
 ('W', 1989, 1991, 30),
 ('W', 1989, 1992, 40)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

First create some test data:

```
CREATE TABLE tblPoints ([User] VARCHAR(100), [Year] INT,Points INT,Value INT)
INSERT INTO tblPoints
SELECT 'A',1997,1,10 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A',1997,2,30 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A',1997,3,40 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A',1999,1,70 UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',1993,1,7 UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',1993,3,4 UNION ALL
SELECT 'C',2001,1,10
```

The concating the columns:

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ','+QUOTENAME('Points'+Points),
                     QUOTENAME('Points'+Points))
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tblPoints.Points ORDER BY tblPoints.Points) AS RowNbr,
            CAST(tblPoints.Points AS VARCHAR(5)) AS Points
        FROM 
            tblPoints
    ) AS tbl
WHERE
    tbl.RowNbr=1
```

Then create the dynamic sql and executing it:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)=
N'SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        tblPoints.[User],
        tblPoints.[Year],
        ''Points''+CAST(tblPoints.Points AS VARCHAR(5)) AS Points,
        tblPoints.Value
    FROM
        tblPoints
) AS p
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Value) FOR Points IN('+@cols+')
) AS pvt
ORDER BY [User]'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

And the because I don't want the point table:

```
DROP TABLE tblPoints
```