# How to display the all records of table as columns in sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with 200 records so i need to show all 200 rows as 200 columns it is not possible to write all 200 records in pivot IN() section as when i insert 201st record in table its column should also to be shown.

```
select * from Table_Name
```

Returns 200 rows

so i need to show 200 columns in other queries

```
SELECT * FROM
(
select RecordName from Table_Name
) AS T
PIVOT (Max(RecordName) FOR MiscMasterName IN (Record1,Record2)) AS T2
```

gives 2 columns
like wise i need 200 columns such that if i add 201st records
and wherever i execute the query i get 201 columns after inserting new record....

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL Pivot? Possibility of creating table columns from row values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922797/t-sql-pivot-possibility-of-creating-table-columns-from-row-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a dynamic pivot. Something like this:

**Test data:**

```
CREATE TABLE Table_Name(MiscMasterName VARCHAR(200),RecordName VARCHAR(200))
INSERT INTO Table_Name
VALUES
    ('Record1','aValue'),
    ('Record2','SomeValue')
```

**Finding the columns**

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @cols=STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT
            ',' +QUOTENAME(MiscMasterName)
        FROM
            Table_Name
    FOR XML PATH('')
    )
,1,1,'')
```

**Declare and executing dynamic sql**

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)=
N'SELECT 
* 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        RecordName,
         MiscMasterName
    from 
        Table_Name
) AS T
PIVOT (Max(RecordName) FOR MiscMasterName IN ('+@cols+')) AS T2'
EXECUTE(@query)
```

**Cleaning up after myself**

```
DROP TABLE Table_Name
```

**Output**

```
Record1 Record2 
aValue  SomeValue
```