# T-SQL : Display logical structured table as flat output

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table, T1, with an ID and some other fields.

I have another table, T2, with an ID (which matches the ID in the 1st table), a sort_order and a value.
The ID and the order are a composite primary key.

For my output I need to have a single row with ID, then value1, value2, value3 ... value*n*
(in practice I'll be stopping at 12)

I can obviously do this by left joining T2 onto T1 multiple times:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.[Other fields], T2_1.Value AS Value1, T2_2.Value AS Value2 ...
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T2 AS T2_1 ON T1.ID = T2_1.ID AND 1 = T2_1.Sort_Order
LEFT JOIN T2 AS T2_2 ON T1.ID = T2_2.ID AND 2 = T2_1.Sort_Order
...
```

But I was wondering if there was a better way? Or at least one that looked neater!

SQL version is 2008.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On SQL-server, `PIVOT` is the keyword you're looking for!

Query:

```
SELECT ID, [Other fields], [1], [2], [3], [4], . . .
FROM (
    SELECT T1.ID, T1.[Other fields], T2.Sort_Order, T2.Value) 
    FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (
    MAX(Value)
    FOR Sort_Order IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], . . .)
) AS PivotTable
```

Check out BOL for more information: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Using dynamic sql, it is also possible to generate the column list dynamically, so you don't have to limit yourself to a fixed number of values. See for example: [T-SQL Pivot? Possibility of creating table columns from row values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922797/t-sql-pivot-possibility-of-creating-table-columns-from-row-values)

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.[Other fields],
       MAX(CASE WHEN T2.Sort_Order = 1 then T2.Value END) AS Value1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN T2.Sort_Order = 2 then T2.Value END) AS Value2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN T2.Sort_Order = 3 then T2.Value END) AS Value3,
       . . .
FROM T1  LEFT JOIN
     T2 T2
     ON T1.ID = T2_1.ID
GROUP BY t1.ID, T1.[Other fields];
```

Comment: That certainly works, as is a lot neater. Why didn't I think of that?
I'll see if anyone else has alternative approaches.