# SQL Server pivot challenge

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, pivot, unpivot

there are two given columns - prefix and datetime, e.g.

```
PREFIX | DATETIME

ABC    | 2010-01-28 07:11:31.000

DEF    | 2010-02-15 07:11:31.000

DEF    | 2010-01-25 07:11:31.000
```

I want to Pivot the data by year/month and prefix.
The result should look like this:

```
YEAR   | MONTH | ABC | DEF |

2010   | Jan   |  1  |  1  |

2010   | Feb   |  0  |  1  |
```

In other words, count how much objects with the same prefix has the same period (year/month).

I tried this code, but it doesn't work and I do not know where is the problem.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(O.OU01) 
                from Test.dbo.Organisation as O
                group by O.OU01
                order by O.OU01
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT [Year], [month], ' + @cols + ' 
        from 
        (
           SELECT Year(A.Stand) Year,
             Datename(month, A.Stand) [month],
             O.OU01
           FROM Test.dbo.Assets as A
           join Test.dbo.Organisation as O on A.Key = O.Key
        ) x
        pivot 
       (
            Count([O.OU01])
            for O.OU01 in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: what have you tried?  Unless your prefixes are predefined (and a pretty small number of them) you'll likely need to go with a dynamic sql solution see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922797/t-sql-pivot-possibility-of-creating-table-columns-from-row-values as an example

Comment: no, the prefix is not predefined. I can not hardcode the prefix in the query

Comment: @SvenMüller what do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: @bluefeet

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Invalid column name 'O.OU01'.

Msg 107, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
The column prefix 'O' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.

Comment: @SvenMüller remove the `O.` alias inside your pivot - change the code to `Count([OU01]) for OU01 in`

Comment: @bluefeet Do you see a chance to order the result first by year and then by month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Conditional Aggregate`

```
SELECT Year([DATETIME]) [Year],
       Datename(month, [DATETIME]) [month],
       Count(CASE WHEN PREFIX = 'ABC' THEN 1 END) ABC,
       Count(CASE WHEN PREFIX = 'DEF' THEN 1 END) DEF
FROM   Tablename
GROUP  BY Year([DATETIME]),
          Datename(month, [DATETIME])
```

Or using `Pivot`

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT Year([DATETIME])            [Year],
               Datename(month, [DATETIME]) [month],
               PREFIX,
               [DATETIME]
        FROM   tablename) a
       PIVOT (Count([DATETIME])
             FOR PREFIX IN ([ABC],
                            [DEF])) AS P
```

### [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb97d/1)

Dynamic Version:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(PREFIX) 
                    from es
                    group by PREFIX
                    order by PREFIX
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT [Year], [month], ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
               SELECT Year(DATETIMEs)            Year,
                 Datename(month, DATETIMEs) [month],
                 PREFIX
               FROM es
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                Count([PREFIX])
                for PREFIX in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb97d/4)

Comment: the prefix is dynamic, I can not hardcode it in the query

Comment: @SvenMüller I've added a dynamic version for you.  NoDisplayName, hope you don't mind that I added that to your answer. :)

Comment: @bluefeet- How would i Mind sir. Thanks for the Dynamic pivot version Pivot Guru :) I learned pivot concept from your answers sir

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL Server's **PIVOT TABLE**

Try this:

```
SELECT Year, MonthName, [ABC], [DEF]
FROM (SELECT YEAR(A.DATETIME) AS Year, DATENAME(A.DATETIME,Getdate()) AS MonthName, 
             A.PREFIX  AS Header, A.DATETIME DATA 
        FROM tableA A
     ) AS A 
PIVOT(COUNT(DATA) FOR Header IN ([ABC], [DEF])) AS P
```

Comment: Missing a `,` after `AS MonthName`

Comment: the prefix is dynamic, I can not hardcode it in the query